# What kind of code is http://ogp.me/ns/fb#

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, xfbml

I'm not asking what it does, in the sense of, "It makes your Facebook Like button work."

What I am asking is, is this javascript, is it css, or what? It looks like a class. If I wanted to write my own similar file, what extension would I use to name it?

The reason I am asking is I would like to make my own class, for my own widgets, and reference my own class by putting something like xmlns:zz="http://mydomain.com/mylibrary/zz#"

Comment: That URL resolves into a JSON object defining the `og:tags` that are used by the Open Graph Protocol...  Your question is too broad in its current state to be answered...  What exactly are you looking to create?  You want to create a similar **service** I imagine... not just a similar file...

Comment: Lix, I think your first sentence answers my question. In other words, it isn't a particular script language, but a JSON output. I think that steers me where I want to take this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [JSON](http://www.json.org/), as the name implies is a subset of JavaScript, but as it is designed for encoding data not code it can actually be parsed by most programming languages.
The extension don't matter but could be `.js` as it is commonly served with the MIME type   `text/javascript`.

The is no way of using it with XML namespaces as you are hoping.

Comment: Cool Barnaby. I'd click this answer "Up", but I don't yet have the street cred.

Comment: Accepting this answer will give you `+2` street credits to get you on your way :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer as the right answer, which it is. Someone downvoted it for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1):

That URL redirects to http://graph.facebook.com/schema/og/#, which returns [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON/).